# Ошибка React Native npm exited with non-zero code: 4294963238

Tags: react-native, expo

Хотел установить `expo install expo-app-loading`.
Выдает такие ошибки, в чем проблема?

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT

npm ERR! syscall rename

npm ERR! path C:\Users\vladg\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\Проекты\RN\NewsMe\newsMySite\node_modules\react-native-web\node_modules\fbjs

npm ERR! dest C:\Users\vladg\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\Проекты\RN\NewsMe\newsMySite\node_modules\react-native-web\node_modules\.fbjs.DELETE

npm ERR! errno -4058

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\vladg\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\Проекты\RN\NewsMe\newsMySite\node_modules\react-native-web\node_modules\fbjs' -> 'C:\Users\vladg\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\Проекты\RN\NewsMe\newsMySite\node_modules\react-native-web\node_modules\.fbjs.DELETE'

npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.

npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\vladg\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-06-26T09_57_28_050Z-debug.log

npm exited with non-zero code: 4294963238
```